# Returns true if it is a vowel, false otherwise

Tags: javascript, forms, function

Below is my code for finding out if a character is a vowel or not. But when I run it, it doesn't print out true or false.

Can someone please help me to see what I am doing wrong?

```js
var vowel = function(str) {
  var matches = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  var count = matches ? matches.length : 0;

  document.getElementByID('p').innerHTML = "'" + str + "contains" + count + "vowel(s)";

  return false;
}

vowel(str);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name='t1'>
  <input type='submit' value="SUBMIT" onclick='return vowel(this.form.t1.v'>
  <div id="p"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is the closing parenthesis in the call to `vowel()` also missing in your actual code?

Comment: You call `vowel(str);`, but where is `str` defined?

Comment: `str` is undefined, \*I guess\*

Comment: try this:   var str = 'aeiffdgj';
var vowel = function(str)   {
      
        var matches = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
        var count = matches ? matches.length: 0;

       // document.getElementByID('p').innerHTML = //"'"+str+"contains"+count+"vowel(s)";
alert(count);
        return false;
        };
    vowel(str);

Comment: thank you everyone. But it is still not returning the result :-(

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Are you mute? The op is calling `vowel(str)`. You think you're right, but you don't understand the op code. He's referencing a variable (he declared an indentifer "str") in the first argument at a call statement. I'm not talking about the function scope itself, I'm talking about this -> `vowel(str)`, not this -> `function(str)`.

Comment: @FREEZE, okay, you know what? We're both right. The questioner does call `vowel(str)` after the function assignment, but *also* calls `vowel(this.form.t1.v)` from their `onclick` attribute.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, but you didn't understand what I said, I wasn't saying about the function scope itself (I KNOW ARGUMENTS HAVE ANY VALUE, THAT'S WHY THEY'RE OPTIONAL)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.getElementByID` try `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with the code.

1- `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`

2- You did not close the bracket for the function call `vowel(this.form.t1.v`

3- `t1.v` is not a property. You meant to use `t1.value`

```js
var vowel = function(str) {
  var matches = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  var count = matches ? matches.length : 0;

  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "'" + str + "' contains " + count + " vowel(s)";

  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="t1" />
  <input type='submit' value="SUBMIT" onclick='return vowel(this.form.t1.value);' />
  <div id="p"></div>
</form>
```